# Qt step by step algorithm animation demonstration

Tags: c++, qt

I am creating the demonstration of the algorithm. *The issue I am facing is how to animate the algorithm step by step, so on timeout or on click the algorithm does one step and presents it on screen.* I want the algorithm below to go one step (as indicated at the lines) at the time, so everytime the function is called it does just one step of the algorithm. The closest to the idea would be like debugging the algorithm - on every call it would go to the next "breakpoint" (step one, two, three in the code)

```
void MainWindow::animationStep()
{
    // this as a whole goes all in one step - for now
    QVector<QVector3D> mp = myView->points; 
    QVector2D p0(mp.back()); // in step one - highlight this point 
    mp.pop_back();
    mp.pop_back();
    while(!mp.empty()){
        QVector2D pTemp(mp.back()); // in step two - highlight this point
        mp.pop_back();
        // in step three - draw this line
        QGraphicsLineItem *line = myView->scene->addLine(p0.x(), p0.y(), pTemp.x(), pTemp.y(), QPen(Qt::blue, 3)); 
        line->setZValue(-1);
        // next step - continue
    }
}
```

I have an idea to put every part in different function and execute them based on the global counter, but that seems to be unnecessarily complicated. Is there some easy way to do that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The question is, how to animate the algortihm, so it does and promote to the GUI just one step at a time.

Comment: I have updated the question. I do admit it was not clear on the first sight

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two ways to accomplish an animated display of running your code.

The first option is to split the code up so that it is operated in steps on call backs.  This will be pretty ugly.  You may be able to use some sort of co-routine package to make it appear less ugly.

The second option is to no actually run the algorithm and display together.  In this situation, when running the algorithm, you would record all the steps in a time based data structure, then have separate code that plays back that data structure to the display.  The downside to this is that now the display code has no way to effect the algorithm as it runs.

Comment: The latter idea seems doable, however putting it into some structure would be complicated anyway (type, way of identifying every step). I got an idea to put every step to a new `QGraphicsView` and put them one by one on top of each other with transparent background. Does it make sense? (seems like a complicated task as well)

Comment: Sure that makes sense.  Your list of QGraphicsViews are just your data structure then.